# Mounted method called twice when used component in page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a modal code in one component which i am using in the page, everything works fine but if I refresh the page than mounted hook called twice which is breaking my code. I want it to called only once.

```js
import axios from '~/plugins/axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {}
    };
  },
  components: {
    LoginSignupModal
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted called......');
  },
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <p>
        <LoginSignupModal :isModalOpen='isModalOpen' v-on:onModalClose="onModalClose($event)"></LoginSignupModal>
      </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot paste div into paragraph.

Remove <p> and it should work.